# PostgreSQL: need to routinely rotate a big table that is mentioned in a view

Tags: postgresql, view

I have a view:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_Foo0 AS
SELECT lotsofstuff
  FROM Bar INNER JOIN LotsOfOtherJoins

CREATE TABLE old_Foo AS SELECT * FROM v_Foo LIMIT 0;

CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW v_Foo AS
SELECT * FROM v_Foo0
 WHERE stuff NOT IN (SELECT stuff FROM old_Foo);

CREATE TABLE Foo AS SELECT * FROM v_Foo LIMIT 0;
```

then I have DML which runs periodically in a procedure, and the normal way could be this:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

INSERT INTO old_Foo SELECT * FROM Foo;

TRUNCATE TABLE Foo;
INSERT INTO Foo SELECT * FROM v_Foo;

...

INSERT INTO Foo 
SELECT * FROM old_Foo
 WHERE (stuff) NOT IN (SELECT stuff FROM old_Foo)

TRUNCATE TABLE old_Foo;

...

COMMIT;
```

The point is Foo is huge, and being re-built, incrementally, based on new stuff not already in Foo. Then lots of other stuff happens, then whatever from the old_Foo is not already in the rebuilt Foo will get copied into the rebuilt Foo and then old_Foo can be deleted.

But there is one unnecessary copy operation where 10s of millions of rows get shuffled around just to hang on to the old stuff. I would prefer just renaming Foo to old_Foo then rebuild the new Foo:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION;

ALTER TABLE Foo RENAME TO old_Foo;

CREATE TABLE Foo AS SELECT * FROM v_Foo LIMIT 0;
INSERT INTO Foo SELECT * FROM v_Foo;

...

INSERT INTO Foo 
SELECT * FROM old_Foo
 WHERE (stuff) NOT IN (SELECT stuff FROM old_Foo)

DROP TABLE old_Foo;

...

COMMIT;
```

Problem is, I can't rename Foo nor drop old_Foo because they are referenced in the v_Foo views. And I want that view referencing whatever table is *called* Foo at the time it's executed, not cling to the table that was called Foo when the view was defined.

The reason for having this view is that it's a multi screen page full query, I don't want to put that into some procedure to be redefined every time. I just want that view there and when time to rebuild this Foo comes, I want it to do its thing.

And in the real world there are many tables like Foo, and I just don't want to redefine these views over and over again verbatim like that in a crazy 5000 line procedure.

Been thinking if I could use a partitioned table, but as soon as I change the partition key, I would have to do an UPDATE which would translate into the same copying of the millions of rows into the old_Foo partition. So nothing would be gained.

Answer (score 4):

I second Arkhena's answer – dropping and re-creating a view is no big deal.

If you want to avoid that, you could resort to a function and base the view on that:

```
CREATE FUNCTION view_fun() RETURNS TABLE (...)
   LANGUAGE sql AS
$$SELECT ... FROM foo WHERE ...$$;

CREATE VIEW foo_view AS SELECT * FROM view_fun();
```

Since a function like this will not depend on `foo`, you can then rename the tables, and because the function does not store the parsed query, it will always use the table that is currently called `foo`.

Comment: I had thought about this, but would that allow optimization to use indexes and stuff? In other words, would the function be transparent to the query planner?

Comment: The function can be inlined if the query is simple enough. Otherwise, the function is an optimization barrier, so `WHERE` conditions wouldn't be optimized into it. Try it for your special case. I think dropping and re-creating the view is better; I only wanted to show an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

The simple without re-thinking everything and assuming everything you do is the only way to do it would be to :

- drop the view
- drop the table
- recreate the view

Another way of doing things would be to create another foo table, make all the changes to it (inserting/deleting) and then drop the view/recreate the view to point to that new table, so that you can now drop the foo table and rename your table as foo.

Dropping or creating a view does not take a long time.

I would still advise to do all your queries in the same transaction so that you can rollback easily and someone connecting to the database will always see a table foo and a view v_foo.

Comment: Of course, that is what I'm trying to avoid. :)

Comment: @Arkhena I have a table with 3 crores of records and on which almost thousands of views have been created. Problem is, this table with 3 crores is a live table e.g. for each month it gets increased by at least one lakh new records. So I need to update the big table each month. So now,   your advice is not almost feasible in this case, is it?

Answer (score 1):

Sadly, the method I wanted to avoid, dropping the view, is the only working method. But I built myself a procedure which can do it for any view, dropping it and recreating it afterwards.

So here is what we do:

1. preserve view definition of v_R from the catalog
2. drop the view v_R
3. rename the table R to old_R
4. create table R as select * from old_R limit 0
5. create view v_R as saved definition
6. copy this grants from old_R to R

Here is the procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE reports.move_to_old(schemaName_ text, tableName_ text) LANGUAGE PlPgSQL AS $$
DECLARE
  _schemaName text := lower(schemaName_);
  _tableName text := lower(tableName_);
  _viewName text := 'v_'||_tableName;
  _definition text :=(SELECT definition
                        FROM pg_views
                       WHERE schemaName = _schemaName
                         AND viewName = _viewName);
  command text;
BEGIN
  EXECUTE 'DROP VIEW '||_schemaName||'.'||_viewName;
  EXECUTE 'ALTER TABLE '||_schemaName||'.'||_tableName||' RENAME TO old_'||_tableName;
  EXECUTE 'CREATE TABLE '||_schemaName||'.'||_tableName||' AS SELECT * FROM '||_schemaName||'.old_'||_tableName||' LIMIT 0';
  EXECUTE 'CREATE VIEW '||_schemaName||'.'||_viewName||E' AS \n'||_definition;
  FOR command IN
    SELECT 'GRANT '||string_agg(privilege_type, ', ')
           ||' ON '||table_schema||'.'||table_name
           ||' TO '||string_agg(distinct grantee, ', ')
      FROM information_schema.role_table_grants
     WHERE table_name = 'old_'||_tableName
       AND table_schema = _schemaName
      GROUP BY table_schema, grantee, table_name
  LOOP
    EXECUTE command;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

And the cool thing is that PostgreSQL as opposed to stupid Oracle can do all of this in a transaction. So here is the test:

```
start transaction;
create or replace view reports.v_foo as select 1 as num, 'aa'::text as name;
create table reports.foo as select * from reports.v_foo limit 0;
insert into reports.foo select * from reports.v_foo;
select * from reports.foo;
call move_to_old('reports', 'foo');
insert into reports.foo select * from reports.v_foo;
insert into reports.foo select * from reports.v_foo;
select * from reports.foo;
select * from reports.old_foo;
rollback;
```